# PHP curl response is in JSON format but var_dump shows string

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm attempting to gather information from Facebook to auto push to a page via Graph API Explorer.

I have the curl request working, it gives me valid JSON (checked with validater).

I get the following error: *Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()*

If I do a var_dump it declares it as a string.

php:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER =>false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

 foreach($response as $posts){
   if($posts['from']['id']='230594106985291'){
      echo "<div class='contentItem'>";
      echo $posts['message'];
      echo "</div>";
    }
  }
```

Sample curl response listed here: http://jsfiddle.net/X933V/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just need to [**`decode your json`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) as an array before looping in it

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$json = json_decode($response, true); //note the second parameter true 
                                    //to have decoded as an associative array
foreach($json as $posts){
```

Comment: You rock, I could've sworn I did that... but I was wrong :)